# Pebble watch - CPU usage

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am developing an app for the pebble watch and I would like to find out the CPU and battery usage of the watch while the app is running. 
I am searching through the [documentation](https://developer.pebble.com/) but I did not find anything so far regarding the CPU usage, nor I found a similar question somewhere.
Is there a way to get that kind of data?